# Display a text message if the shortcode is not found?

Tags: php, plugin-development, shortcode

I'm using the `do_shortcode` function to add a shortcode in a page. But I would like to check if that shortcode exists before displaying it. If the user has no gallery, I would like to display a message like this: "Sorry no gallery here".

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
/**
* galeries content
*/

function iconic_galeries_endpoint_content() {
echo /* Template Name: Client Area */

get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">
        <article>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1><?php _e( 'Vos galeries photos.', 'my-theme' ); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
            <?php
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

            if ( isset( $current_user->user_email ) ) {
                echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( '%s, this is your galleries', 'my-theme' ), $current_user->display_name ) . ':</p>';
                echo do_shortcode( '[picu_list_collections email="' . $current_user->user_email . '"]' );
            }
            else {
                echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="%s">log in</a> to see this page', 'my-theme' ), wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ) . '.</p>';
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

<?php
}
```

I haven't found a way to return a message like: "Sorry no gallery here".

Does anyone have a solution?

---

When client has a gallery to approve
[image: Client has no galerie to approve]

And when client has no gallery to approve or he has already approve his photos
[image: Client has a gallery to approve]

Comment: Have you tried the core function `shortcode_exists( 'picu_list_collections' )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_shortcode()` returns content with shortcodes filtered out. We can check the return value and display appropriate message accordingly.

```
$output = do_shortcode( '[picu_list_collections email="' . $current_user->user_email . '"]' );

// the shortcode returns an empty <ul> tag, if there is no gallery 
// https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/picu/trunk/frontend/includes/picu-template-functions.php#L464

if($output == '<ul class="picu-collection-list"></ul>') echo "Nothing here";
else echo $output;
```

I hope this may help!

**References:**

1. [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)
2. [[picu_list_collections]](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/picu/trunk/frontend/includes/picu-template-functions.php#L464)

Comment: Thanks Qaisar, your code display no message but work when gallery exist, it seems may be a parameter I forgot

Comment: @NicolasLogerot , I, in my answer, assumed that  if there is no gallery, then the output of your shortcode is an empty string i.e. `""` . Can you tell what is the output of shortcode when there is no gallery, or you can replace `""` in my code with that output.

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't know how to find the output of shot code when is no gallery

Comment: What is output just after the **this is your galleries USER_NAME** when page is loaded?

Comment: OK, Can you share screenshots in cases of a user has no galleries?

Comment: Updated my code after checking source code for the shortcode [here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/picu/trunk/frontend/includes/picu-template-functions.php#L464). **Let me know if it works now?**

Comment: Whao! it work THANK YOU VERY MUCH, Your a boss!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. Please do accept it as **Accepted answer** and **Up-Vote**, so the other people searching for similar issue know the answer. Thanks

Comment: Ok I'll do it and THANK YOU very much you save my day

Comment: Stay blessed! Always.

Answer (score 1):

This is a curious piece of code. Apparently users can upload a gallery, but your snippet does not show the upload code, so it's impossible to know how it is stored and hence to access to find out if it exists.

Presumably, the `picu_list_collections` shortcode knows how to access the gallery, but if there is no gallery you want it to return different output. That would mean modifying the [shortcode function itself](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

If you can only modify the current function you must not echo the result, but store it in a variable. Then you can perform a test on it to establish it the returned code reflects the existence of a gallery, for instance by testing it for an `img`-tag. Like this:

```
$gall = do_shortcode( '[picu_list_collections email="' . $current_user->user_email . '"]' );
if (false=strpos($gall,'<img')) echo 'Sorry no here' else echo $gall;
```